# How to go about using super();

Tags: java

I am just wondering what is super() and how it works. I have (general) idea, but I'm not quite sure about it. I'm wondering if this is right:

```
class ExampleClass extends File{
 public ExampleClass(String str){
    super(str);
 }
}
```

I am also wondering if super(); is actually helpful / efficient its use.

Comment: `super(...)` has nothing to do with _helpful/efficient_, it's a Java language feature needed to initialise an object hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

`super()` calls the constructor of the the super class (the class extended by the class in which the call is made).

Comment: Would that code then be correct??